# Why does ITypeInfo::Invoke return 0x80020003 (Member not found.)?

Tags: c++, events, com, activex, ole

I am having trouble implementing an event sink for [DShellWindowsEvents from SHDocVw.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc836565(v=vs.85).aspx) in Microsoft Visual C++.

The problem arises inside my implementation of IDispatch::Invoke. I implemented it by delegating its call to ITypeInfo::Invoke (as [suggested by Microsoft on remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479(v=vs.85).aspx)), but it always fails with error code 0x80020003 (Member not found).

It is interesting though that DShellWindowsEvents has only two methods (WindowRegistered and WindowRevoked) and ITypeInfo::GetIDsOfNames works successfully for both, returning the expected DISPID. But then how does it give "Member not found" error for Invoke?

The relevant part of the type library:

```
[
  uuid(FE4106E0-399A-11D0-A48C-00A0C90A8F39),
  helpstring("Event interface for IShellWindows")
]
dispinterface DShellWindowsEvents {
    properties:
    methods:
        [id(0x000000c8), helpstring("A new window was registered.")]
        void WindowRegistered([in] long lCookie);
        [id(0x000000c9), helpstring("A new window was revoked.")]
        void WindowRevoked([in] long lCookie);
};

[
  uuid(9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39),
  helpstring("ShellDispatch Load in Shell Context")
]
coclass ShellWindows {
    [default] interface IShellWindows;
    [default, source] dispinterface DShellWindowsEvents;
};
```

and my actual code where it all happens:

```
class CDShellWindowsEvents : public DShellWindowsEvents {

public:
    // IUnknown implementation
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface( REFIID riid, LPVOID *ppvObj )
    {
        if( ppvObj == NULL )  return E_INVALIDARG;
        *ppvObj = NULL;
        if(  riid == IID_IUnknown  ||  riid == IID_IDispatch  ||  riid == DIID_DShellWindowsEvents  )
        {
            *ppvObj = this;
            AddRef( );
            return NOERROR;
        }
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef( )
    {
        InterlockedIncrement( &m_cRef );
        return m_cRef;
    }

    virtual ULONG __stdcall Release( )
    {
        ULONG ulRefCount = InterlockedDecrement( &m_cRef );
        if( 0 == m_cRef )
            delete this;
        return ulRefCount;
    }


    // IDispatch implementation
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeInfoCount( unsigned int * pctinfo )
    {
        if( pctinfo == NULL )  return E_INVALIDARG;
        *pctinfo = 1;
        return NOERROR;
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeInfo( unsigned int iTInfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo ** ppTInfo )
    {
        if( ppTInfo == NULL )  return E_INVALIDARG;
        *ppTInfo = NULL;

        if( iTInfo != 0 )  return DISP_E_BADINDEX;

        *ppTInfo = m_pTypeInfo;
        m_pTypeInfo->AddRef();
        return NOERROR;
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, OLECHAR ** rgszNames, unsigned int cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID * rgDispId )
    {
        return  m_pTypeInfo->GetIDsOfNames( rgszNames, cNames, rgDispId );
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS * pDispParams, VARIANT * pVarResult, EXCEPINFO * pExcepInfo, unsigned int * puArgErr )
    {
        // We could switch on dispIdMember here but we want to do this the flexible way, so we can easily implement it later for dispinterfaces with dozens of methods.

        return  m_pTypeInfo->Invoke( this, dispIdMember, wFlags, pDispParams, pVarResult, pExcepInfo, puArgErr );

        /*HRESULT ret;
        switch( dispIdMember )
        {
        case 0x000000c8:    ret = WindowRegistered( pDispParams->rgvarg[0].intVal );  break;
        case 0x000000c9:    ret = WindowRevoked( pDispParams->rgvarg[0].intVal );  break;
        default:            ret = DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND;
        }
        if( pVarResult )  pVarResult->lVal = ret;
        return ret;*/
    }


    // DShellWindowsEvents implementation
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall WindowRegistered( int nCookie )
    {
        LOG( "CDShellWindowsEvents::WindowRegistered( nCookie=0x%X ) ." , nCookie );
        return NOERROR;
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall WindowRevoked( int nCookie )
    {
        LOG( "CDShellWindowsEvents::WindowRevoked( nCookie=0x%X ) ." , nCookie );
        return NOERROR;
    }


    // Constructor
    CDShellWindowsEvents( )
    {
        m_cRef = 1;

        LoadRegTypeLib( LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 0, LANG_NEUTRAL, &m_pTypeLib );
        m_pTypeLib->GetTypeInfoOfGuid( DIID_DShellWindowsEvents, &m_pTypeInfo );
    }


    // Destructor
    ~CDShellWindowsEvents( )
    {
        m_pTypeInfo->Release( );
        m_pTypeLib->Release( );
    }


private:
    ULONG m_cRef;
    ITypeLib *m_pTypeLib;
    ITypeInfo *m_pTypeInfo;
};
```

Is this a problem with the type library not specifying dual for the dispinterface? If yes, is there a way to force ITypeInfo::Invoke to threat it as dual since I know its vtable is in order.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[A `dispinterface` is an automation-only interface, not a dual interface.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  So, `DShellWindowsEvents` only natively has the 7 methods of `IDispatch`, not the extra 2 it declares.  It's like declaring an `IDispatch`-only interface with a contract, such as predefined DISPIDs.

To use `ITypeLib::Invoke` in that fashion, you need to declare your own interface as `[dual]` with the extra methods.

```
[ object, dual, oleautomation, uuid(...) ]
interface IMyDualShellWindowsEvents : IDispatch
{
    [id(0x000000c8), helpstring("A new window was registered.")]
    HRESULT WindowRegistered([in] long lCookie);
    [id(0x000000c9), helpstring("A new window was revoked.")]
    HRESULT WindowRevoked([in] long lCookie);
}
```

You'll need provide or embed your own typelib and load it instead.

`DShellWindowsEvents` is a dispinterface, so your events object won't be `QueryInterface`d for your internal interface, although you may handle that case anyway.  As such, you don't need to register your typelib, just load it with `LoadLibraryEx`.

I think you may add `hidden, restricted` to the interface attributes, so it doesn't show up and can't be used in e.g. VBA, even by manually adding a reference to such a *private* typelib.